# Client Server Communication in ns3

Tags: client-server, ns-3

I want to simulate an UDP request-response application in ns3 by using 802.11n as communication technology, where a client/server **A** an access point **AP** and another server/client **B** exchange some messages (where each message has a particular size, i.e. 100, 130, 235 byte and so on):

```
*A*         AP          *B*


A------>AP

AP------>A

AP------>B


B------>AP

AP------>B

AP------>A


A------>B

B------->A
```

I followed this tutorial(https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_make_and_use_a_new_application) and I'm able to send and receive data with custom size but just for the first interaction. Furthermore I spent a lot of days to understand how can is possible modify the behavior of this application in order to simulate the aforementioned scenario. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to simulate? Are you using TCP or UDP? Do you have any nodes in between the servers and the client? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @Thiago thank you for your suggestions. I improved my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new application. NS-3 already has applications that send traffic according to your specification (e.g. BulkSend Application, OnOff, and so on). [Here's the link](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__applications.html).

Regarding your application, it is very close to this same application using a client/server over wireless lan ([link](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/udp-client-server_8cc_source.html)).

All you have to do is tweak the parameters. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you @Thiago, but in my case, I want to send the first message to AP; IF AP receive that message, then AP response to A with a message, and after that, AP will send another message to B and so on. Precisely I want to manage these messages exchange with conditions, so I think that it's not possible to use just the suggested applications. Do you think that can I make this scenario by reusing this app and by modifying the actual model behaviour (i.e. udp-client-server.cc and .h)?

Comment: You might need to modify the `netdevice` to achieve what you want. Also, you are more likely to get a more specialized answer from the official NS3 mailing list on Google Groups.